# Irreducible components: associativity for intersections?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, projective-varieties

Let $A$, $B$, $C$ be closed irreducible subvarieties of $\mathbb{A}^n$. Let $V_1$ be an irreducible component of $B\cap C$, and $V$ an irreducible component of $A\cap V_1$. Must there
necessarily be an irreducible component $W_1$ of $A\cap B$ such that $V$ equals some irreducible component of $W_1\cap C$?

Comment: Why can't you just take $W_1$ to be any irreducible component of $A \cap B$ which contains $V$?

Comment: Why would that necessarily work? There would then be an irreducible component of $W_1\cap C$ that *contains* $V$, but would there have to be an irreducible component of $W_1\cap C$ that *equals* $V$?

Comment: Right, it is slightly more subtle. See my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

This is an example with irreducible (and nonsingular) $A,B,C$: Consider $\mathbb{A}^4$ with coordinates $(w,x, y, z)$. Let $B$ be the $(x,y)$-plane (i.e. the set $w = z = 0$), $C$ be the hypersurface $z = xy$, and $A$ be the $(y,z)$-plane. Then $B \cap C$ is the union of the "$x$-axis" and "$y$-axis". Let $V_1$ be "$x$-axis" and $V$ be the origin, which is the only irreducible component of $A \cap V_1$. Since $A \cap B$ is the "$y$-axis", which is irreducible, the only possibility for $W_1$ is $y$-axis. But $W_1 \cap C = W_1 \neq V$.

Note that each of $A, B, C$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^k$ (for an appropriate $k$).

**Original Example:** Consider $\mathbb{A}^4$ with coordinates $(w,x, y, z)$. Let $B$ be the $(x,y)$-plane (i.e. the set $w = z = 0$), $C$ be the union of the $(w,x)$-plane and the $(w,y)$-plane and $A$ be the $(y,z)$-plane. Then $B \cap C$ is the union of the "$x$-axis" and "$y$-axis", whereas $A \cap B = A \cap C = A \cap B \cap C$ is the "$y$-axis", so that the property fails with $V_1$ equal to the "$x$-axis".

Comment: In this example, $C$ is reducible.

Comment: Moreover, $V$ can only be the origin or the $y$-axis, so it seems this isn't a counterexample at all - not even if (as in D. Dona's answer) the condition that $C$ be irreducible is dropped.

Comment: @HAHelfgott: I missed the requirement for irreducibility - now updated the answer.

Comment: It just occurred to me that the same works even in $\mathbb{A}^{3}$, forgetting about the $w$ coordinate. In that case the counterexample is truly "minimal", since $\mathbb{A}^{2}$ doesn't have enough room to house a counterexample.

Answer (score 3):

To give more context for possible answers: at the very least, a counterexample exists if we drop the assumption that $A,B,C$ be all irreducible (arisen in conversations with Harald). In $\mathbb{A}^{5}$, take
\begin{align*}
A & =\{x_{4}=0,x_{3}^{2}-x_{5}-1=0\}, \\
B & =\{x_{5}=0\}, \\
C & =\{x_{1}^{2}-x_{2}^{2}x_{3}^{2}=0,x_{1}-x_{2}x_{3}+x_{4}=0\}, \\
V_{1} & =\{x_{1}+x_{2}x_{3}=0,-2x_{2}x_{3}+x_{4}=0,x_{5}=0\}, \\
V & =\{x_{1}=x_{2}=x_{4}=x_{5}=0,x_{3}=1\}.
\end{align*}
Then the two candidates for $W_{1}$ are $W_{1}=\{x_{4}=x_{5}=0,x_{3}=1\}$ and $W_{1}=\{x_{4}=x_{5}=0,x_{3}=-1\}$: the second one does not contain $V$, while the first one gives
\begin{equation*}
W_{1}\cap C=\{x_{1}-x_{2}=0,x_{3}=1,x_{4}=x_{5}=0\},
\end{equation*}
which is irreducible already. In this example, $A,B$ are irreducible but $C$ is not.

Comment: Aah, I see you beat me to it!

Comment: @auniket That's easy when you know the question _before_ it's being posted on MO. But kudos to you for giving an all-irreducibles counterexample!

Comment: How should the weird sentence *"a counterexample exists when $A,B,C$ are not all irreducible"* be interpreted? that there's no counterexample with $A,B,C$ all irreducible?

Comment: @YCor My bad, I see how it can be misinterpreted. I mean _"a counterexample exists if we drop the assumption that $A,B,C$ be all irreducible"_: the counterexample with $A,B,C$ all irreducible exists, see auniket's answer, although I didn't know that yet when I was writing the first time. I'll reformulate.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A \cap B = \cup W_i$, where $W_i$ are the irreducible components.
Then
$$
A \cap B \cap C = (\cup W_i) \cap C = \cup (W_i \cap C).
$$
Assume that $W_i \cap C = \cup Z_{i,j}$, where $Z_{i,j}$ are the irreducible components. Then
$$
A \cap B \cap C  = \cup Z_{i,j}.
$$
In particular, the irreducible component $V$ is the union of some $Z_{i,j}$.
But every $Z_{i,j}$ is closed in $A \cap B \cap C$, hence, irreducibility of $V$
imples that $V = Z_{i,j}$ for some $i$ and $j$. Then the component $W_i$ is the one you need.

Comment: Is it clear that $V$ is the union of some $Z_{i,j}$?